# Breadth First Search using Adjacency List

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, doubly-linked-list

I need to implement a breadth-first search and I am having trouble with the `adjList` (neighbor's list) for my vertex `temp`. First I find the vertex in my `vertexList` list then mark as `visited` and enqueue it. Then while the queue is not empty I check for all neighbors of the enqueued vertex: `temp` who are not visited, mark as visited and enqueue, and so on. **But I don't know for what reason it says my `adjList` (neighbors list) is empty**, which is not according to my display method when I actually print all vertices and its neighbors.

```
void testBreadthFirstSearch(string x)
    {
        vertex * s = findVertex(x);
        list<vertex*> q;

        s->visited = true;
        s->predecessor = s;
        q.push_back(s);

        while (!q.empty()) {

            vertex * temp = q.front();
            q.pop_front(); 

            for (list<vertex*>::iterator itr = temp->adjList.begin(); itr != temp->adjList.end(); itr++) {

                if ((*itr)->visited == false) {
                    (*itr)->visited = true;
                    (*itr)->predecessor = s;
                    q.push_back(*itr);
                }
            }//end for
        }//end while
```

Here is my graph and vertex class:

```
class directedGraph
{
private:
    class vertex
    {
    public:
        string data;
        bool visited;
        vertex * predecessor;
        list<vertex*> adjList;

        vertex(string x)
        {
            data = x;
            visited = false;
        }
    };

    list<vertex*> vertexList;
```

Comment: its you who can debug your program better, isn't it?

Comment: I've been debugging for a while but, I still haven't figured out why.

Comment: `adjList` is empty according to the code you posted. Maybe you must make the initialization more streamlined.